# Getting error TypeError: Object has no member 'forEach' in javascript while returning array from setup method in k6

Tags: javascript, k6

When I am trying to return an array from setup method and try to use it in VU method, I am getting the below error

**TypeError: Object has no member 'forEach' in javascript**

Please find below my code;

```
export function getResponseMapStub() {
  var jsonStub = getAllStubs(urlGetAllStubs, applicationName);
  var listOfMapStubs = [];
  listStubMap.forEach(mapStub => {
    let mapStubInfo = new Map();
    listOfMapStubs.push(mapStubInfo);
  })
  var listOfResponseMapStubs = [];
  var counter = 0; listOfMapStubs.forEach(mapStubResponse => {
    counter++;
    let responseMapStub = convertStubInfoJsonToMap(mapStubResponse);
    listOfResponseMapStubs.push(responseMapStub);
  })
  return listOfResponseMapStubs;
}

export function setup(){
    var listOfResponseMapStubs = getResponseMapStub();
    return listOfResponseMapStubs;
}

export default function (listOfResponseMapStubs) {
    
if(!listOfResponseMapStubs){
    console.error("No data found for test");
    return;
}
listOfResponseMapStubs.forEach(rowMapData => {
    var rowData = mapToObj(rowMapData);
    sleep(0.1) ;
});
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Did you check the type of your the return value? Sounds like you're getting an Object back and not an Array.

Comment: yes . I am getting object type and not array, But why? the method getResponseMapStub() is returning array then why listOfResponseMapStubs  is coming as an object

Comment: how did you determine type? `typeof` will return `'object'` for an Array as well as an Object. `console.log()` your response and look at what it's giving you, or use `Array.isArray(listOfResponseMapStubs)` to determine if it's an array or not.

Comment: yeah i figured out even listOfResponseMapStubs is coming as an object rather than array . however I have declared it s an array.. Basically I am trying to create a array of Objects and try to return it.

Comment: If you post a sample of the return data it would be easier to help.

Comment: I did check it and it seems to work find if I just return an array. Please if this continues open a bug and try to minimize the example